# Collocations frequency dictionary of English

Tags: english, reference-request, frequency, collocations

I am looking for a top list of the most frequent collocations in English.

The desirable size of the list is more than 1000 items.

The best that I found so far is [this collocations list by EnglishClub](https://www.englishclub.com/ref/Collocations/).
It is a good list with descriptions, however, it is sorted by alphabet, not by frequency of usage.

Please advise where I can find such a list.

Comment: Why do you care about raw collocations (vs idiomatic coloquializations)?

Comment: Because collocations it is essential part of English. I'd like just to have the top list of most usable. But as I can see it is not easy to find. The easiest way is just to took some book like Collocations in use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one that looks well-researched (starting on p. 214 with the appendix): [The high frequency collocations of spoken and written English](http://www.academia.edu/8563631/The_high_frequency_collocations_of_spoken_and_written_English)

This one is only for spoken English: [Beyond single words - The most frequent collocations in spoken English](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/240584201_Beyond_single_words_The_most_frequent_collocations_in_spoken_English)

Comment: Thanks, actually I've already came across these ones. I'd like to find the longer with number of collocations around several thousands (3k-4k)